# Type Error: Cannot Read property 'content' of undefined- Discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I made a bot with discord.js to detect when any element of the array `blacklisted` is said. It deletes the message and relays a warning. My friends try work-arounds and try to edit the message to say a bad word, (It doesn't read that). So I ask some friends and they suggest putting the detection in a function and when I use client.on so detect a message update. I am currently receive errors whenever it runs.

Here is the relavent code:

```js
function find(msg) {
 var blacklisted = [
  'words',
  'that',
  'I',
  'cant',
  'say',
  'on',
  'this',
  'website',
 ];

 let foundInText = false;
 for (var i in blacklisted) {
  if (
   msg.content
    .replace(/\s/g, '')
    .replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9]/g, '')
    .toLowerCase()
    .includes(blacklisted[i].toLowerCase())
  )
   foundInText = true;
 }

 if (foundInText) {
  msg.delete();
  msg.reply('Watch your language, dont be a bad boy');
 }
}

client.on('messageUpdate', (oldMessage, newMessage) => {
 find();
});
```

Comment: I didn't work with discord before, but I think you are not passing anything to find().
he is complaining that msg is undefined.

Comment: so what do you suppose I should do then?

Comment: You just need to pass the `msg` parameter. Change `find()` to `find(newMessage)`. Also, why do you have so many `String.prototype.replace()` functions? As far as I know, you don't need any of them,

Comment: try 

client.on('messageUpdate',(oldMessage,newMessage) => {
    find(oldMessage)
});

Comment: @NomairGhanem I tried that and this time it says "msg is undefined" in reference to msg.delete()

Comment: I think the problem is passing the old message, which had been updated try to pass the new message
client.on('messageUpdate',(oldMessage,newMessage) => { find(newMessage) });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments you need to pass the message object to the function. Additionally your method of checking for the words doesn't really work and leads to the bot simply deleting the message, regardless if the wanted words from `blacklisted` are in it or not.

Try this

```js
function find(msg) {
 var blacklisted = [
  'words',
  'that',
  'I',
  'cant',
  'say',
  'on',
  'this',
  'website',
 ];

 let foundInText = false;
 // Convert the content of the message into an array
 // Check if blacklisted contains the element
 msg.content.toLowerCase().split(/ +/g).forEach((element) => {
  if (blacklisted.includes(element)) {
   return (foundInText = true);
  }
 });

 if (foundInText) {
  msg.delete();
  msg.reply('Watch your language, dont be a bad boy');
 }
}

client.on('messageUpdate', (oldMessage, newMessage) => {
 // Return here so the bot doesn't react to it's own messages
 if (message.author.bot) return;

 // Pass the newMessage because we need the message after
 // it has been modified
 find(newMessage);
});

client.on('message', (message) => {
 // Return here so the bot doesn't react to it's own messages
 if (message.author.bot) return;

 // Pass the message
 find(message);

 // The rest of your code
});
```

Comment: I think the `String.prototype.split` function isn't OP's best bet. For example, if one of the words was `'hello'`, then using your method, `'helloo'` would still pass. What was wrong with OPs original method?

Comment: when I tested it, it kept deleting the message even though the words in `blacklisted` weren't in it.

Comment: well I mean I my original method still allows a naughty A-word when saying, password. Because people have to be able to type, "password","pass","bass","sass". Stuff like that would trigger mine too, although Im not really concerned about that problem. Would your ```String.prototype.split``` still work on ```words that have symbols and white space to fool it```? That and the past messages is all I care about.

Comment: well, in my opinion at a certain point it becomes unpractical to use a bot for content moderation beyond basic words. If you want your bot to recognize symbols or emojis that have a dirty meaning we are moving towards machine learning because humans will always be able to make associations that are dirty or naughty from perfectly harmless words. That being said, it should work on symbols if you add those symbols to `blacklisted`. Whitespaces are more difficult because the bot would need to _know_ what letters belong together which brings us back to machine learning.

Comment: @Worthy Alpaca In my original code I implicated ``.replace(/\s/g, '')
    .replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9]/g, '')
    .toLowerCase()``. Could I use that on this one?

Comment: Theoretically yes but it's not really practical. That is because `.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9]/g, '')` removes all whitespaces from the message. That also means that if you have a word like the naughty A word from above, the filter would react and potentially delete a completly harmless message. If you were to use it like that, it would look something like this https://hastebin.com/muvuzavami.js

Comment: and again, if you want your bot to recognize this `pASSword` as a bad word we get into areas that aren't covered with 10 lines of code 

Comment: Thanks @WorthyAlpaca you just summed that up all pretty well. I will check if it works later. Since im new to stack overflow am I like...suppose to do something when(if) the question is answered?

Comment: well, if you liked the answer you can mark is as "useful" and also accept it with the check mark. I'd appreciate it but you don't need to

Comment: It appears your link isn't working for some reason? Is that a glitch on my part?

Comment: are you talking about this link https://hastebin.com/muvuzavami.js ? EDIT: I see what you mean. Hold on...

Comment: this should be a little more permanent https://paste.fuelrats.com/muhiteduqu.js

Comment: Okay thank you. I marked it as useful, I made just a few slight changes to fit the rest of my other non relevant code. It works like a charm. :)